# put data of each year in group of 5 years

Tags: php, date

I have a code that will generate a table of years that is split into groups of  5 years each..How do I put each data of each year in its respective column?

This is what I got so far.

```
$chunkSize = 5;
    $starting_year  = 2006;
    $ending_year    = date("Y");

    for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++) {
        $years[] = $starting_year;
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < count($years); $i+=5)
    {

        echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>";
        echo '<thead><tr>';
            echo '<th class="text-center">'.implode('<th class="text-center">', array_slice($years, $i, $chunkSize)).'</th>';
       echo '</tr></thead>';
           echo '<tr>';


    $result= $myDB->query("SELECT total FROM ".$myDB->prefix("statistics")." WHERE year='$years[$i]'") or die(mysql_error()); 
     $row = $myDB->fetchArray($result);
       $total=$row['total'];

        //echo "<td class='text-center'>".$total."</td>";
    echo '<th class="text-center">'.implode('<th class="text-center">', array_slice($total, $i, $chunkSize)).'</th>';


       echo '</tr>';



    }
    echo "</table>";
```

current output
[image]

Desired result

```
2016    2017            
total  total          
2011    2012    2013    2014    2015
total  total   total    total  total
2006    2007    2008    2009    2010
total  total   total    total  total
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $chunkSize = 5;
  $starting_year  = 2006;
  $ending_year    = date("Y");
  //create an array of years
  $years = range($starting_year,$ending_year); 
  //[2006,2007,....,2016,2017]

  //split years in required size
  $chunked = array_chunk($years,$chunkSize);
  //[ [2006,....,2010], [2011,...2015], [2016,2017]]

  //reverse it
  $reversed = array_reverse($chunked); 
  //[ [2016,2017], [2011,...2015], [2006,....,2010]]

  echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'><tbody>";
  foreach($reversed as $reverse) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($reverse as $year) {
      echo "<th>{$year}</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    foreach($reverse as $year) {
      $result= $myDB->query("SELECT total FROM ".$myDB->prefix("statistics")." WHERE year='{$year}'") or die(mysql_error());
      echo "<td>{$result['total']}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</tbody></table>";
```

The code can be optimized more, but this will do the job.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer..its working fine..Have a nice day